# How to copy a row in an SQL table, insert it into the same table, and append "-Copy" to the end of the name?

Tags: php, sql

I need to copy a full row in an SQL table but add "-Copy" to the end of the MarketName for the copied row.  I have the following:

```
$CopyMarket = "INSERT INTO Markets (MarketName, Size)
                     (SELECT MarketName, Size)
                     FROM Markets
                     WHERE MarketID=$CopyID";
```

How do I append "-Copy" to the MarketName?

ie: The name is "Colorado," I want to copy it and insert as a new row as "Colorado-Copy"

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function from MySQL to append or prepend data. Also work in standard SQL.

Append

```
$CopyMarket = "INSERT INTO Markets (MarketName, Size)
                 (SELECT CONCAT(MarketName, '-Copy'), Size)
                 FROM Markets
                 WHERE MarketID=$CopyID"; // Field-Copy
```

Prepend

```
$CopyMarket = "INSERT INTO Markets (MarketName, Size)
                 (SELECT CONCAT('Copy-', MarketName), Size)
                 FROM Markets
                 WHERE MarketID=$CopyID"; // Copy-Field
```

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) :

Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings, the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent binary string form; if you want to avoid that, you can use an explicit type cast, as in this example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(int_col AS CHAR), char_col);
```

CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');
    -> 'MySQL'
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', NULL, 'QL');
    -> NULL
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(14.3);
    -> '14.3'
```

For quoted strings, concatenation can be performed by placing the strings next to each other:

```
mysql> SELECT 'My' 'S' 'QL';
    -> 'MySQL'
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much.  Worked perfectly.